# Issue with comma initialisation in Eigen c++

Tags: c++, initialization, eigen

I have a problem where the comma initialisation indicated in the Eigen tutorial [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html) doesn't seem to be working.

I have a system where I have a main section where a vector is initialised:

Main:

```
VectorXd v;
```

and a function:

```
double useVector(VectorXd &v) {
    dataI = model_.find();
    v << model_[dataI].v[0], model_[dataI].v[1], model_[dataI].v[2], 1;
    return dataI;
}
```

Note: the function is used like this:

```
double distance = useVector(v);
```

Now the `model_[dataI].v` is a `double[3]` and it is definitely working. My understanding is that this is the same as this:

```
VectorXd v;
v << 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     7, 8, 9;
```

but it is not working, the code is seg-faulting at the comma initialization phase in function.

Note that this works:

```
v.resize(4)
v[0] = model_[dataI].v[0];
v[1] = model_[dataI].v[1];
v[2] = model_[dataI].v[2];
v[3] = 1;
```

as long as v is initialised, like this:

```
VectorXd v(4);
```

which immediately makes me wonder about the point of the resize (but if I take it away then it seg-faults again).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the vector v **must** be resized to the appropriate size before using the comma initializer.

Comment: What is the point of using `VectorXd` if you have to resize the vector manually? I thought Eigen should be able to handle that.

Comment: The reasons are twofolds. First, we don't make difference between `VectorXd` and `MatrixXd` (both are a `Matrix<...>`) and for the later we really have to know the sizes to properly layout the given entries. Second, this permits to directly insert the elements within the target `VectorXd` without having to realloc all the times.